# How can I verify whether a Func<> property has been initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a Func property on my class as below.

```
public class ClassA {

  public Func<string, IClassB> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Checking `MyProperty` for null is not possible. Therefore my question is if it it possible to verify that `MyProperty` has been initialized in some way?

EDIT: I wasn't giving you my whole picture because i beleived it was exactly the same for Func in general. Sorry for that.

Thing is that I am actually instantiating the property using reflection and ahead of this I pick up the value of MyProperty to set it only when it is not instantiated.

```
...
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (var property in properties)
{
if (Attribute.IsDefined(property,typeof(WireAttribute)))
{
var propertyValue = property.GetValue(objectToWire, null);

if (propertyValue == null)  //<-- THIS IS NOT TRUE FOR FUNC RETURN TYPES
...
```

For regular properties, not Func return type it works as expected.

Comment: By _initialized in some way_, do you mean somewhere in the source code? Well, there is _Roslyn_... Although, using _has been_ implies the existence of a changed state in the past, hence some sort of execution thread. Please give us more details.

Comment: Why can't you simply `MyProperty == null`?

Comment: Why checking MyProperty for null is not possible?

Comment: If MyProperty is an event then you're right. you can't check outside of the class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, you can check if the property has been initialized. What you can't check is the value returned by it's invocation, as the invocation is dynamic.

```
class Program
{
    interface IClassB { }
    class ClassB1 : IClassB { }
    class ClassB2 : IClassB { }
    class ClassA
    {
        public Func<string, IClassB>
            MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var classA = new ClassA();

        Console.WriteLine((classA.MyProperty == null)
            ? "Not initialized" : "Initialized");

        classA.MyProperty = (a) =>
        {
            if (a == "1")
                return new ClassB1();
            else if (a == "2")
                return new ClassB2();
            else
                return null;
        };

        Console.WriteLine((classA.MyProperty == null)
            ? "Not initialized" : "Initialized");

        object
            c1 = classA.MyProperty.Invoke("1"),
            c2 = classA.MyProperty.Invoke("2"),
            c3 = classA.MyProperty.Invoke("3");

        Console.WriteLine((c1 != null) ? c1.GetType().Name : "null");
        Console.WriteLine((c2 != null) ? c2.GetType().Name : "null");
        Console.WriteLine((c3 != null) ? c3.GetType().Name : "null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        ClassA clsA = new ClassA();
        if (clsA.MyProperty == null)
            MessageBox.Show("IsNull");

        clsA.MyProperty = new Func<string, bool>(x => x.Equals("1"));

        MessageBox.Show(clsA.MyProperty == null ? "IsNull" : "IsNotNull");
```

this works very good

Answer (score 1):

If I take your code and do

```
 var a = new ClassA();
 var initialized = a.MyProperty == null;
```

the code is perfectly valid. Therefore your assertion is incorrect, checking for `null` is possible.

---

What are you trying to achieve, perhaps you want something like.

```
public class ClassA
{
    private readonly Func<string, IClassB> myFunc;

    public ClassA(Func<string, IClassB> myFunc)
    {
        this.myFunc = myFunc;
    }

    public IClassB MyFunc(string input)
    {
        if (this.myFunc = null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return this.myFunc(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by standard means, like this:

```
   IClassB a = new IClassB();

   //it is null now so Empty will follow
   if (a.MyProperty == null) Console.WriteLine("Empty");
   else Console.WriteLine("Not empty");

   a.MyProperty = new Func<string, IClassB>((s)=>{ return new IClassB(); });
   //it is not null now so Not empty will follow
   if (a == null) Console.WriteLine("Empty");
   else Console.WriteLine("Not empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, you may use a property for the `Func` (if you want/can to test this inside ClassA):

```
public class ClassA {
   private Func<string, IClassB> myProperty;

   public Func<string, IClassB> MyProperty { 
      get {
          if (myProperty == null)
             return some default behaviour;

          return myProperty;
      } 

      set { 
          myProperty = value; 
      }
}
```